# Is there a jQuery plugin for closable overlays?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need a jQuery plugin that displays an overlay at the top of the screen, for notifications.

It needs to be closable. Preferably, it's text should be updatable (without closing and opening a new one - I don't want a second animation if the overlay is already displayed when the text is updated).

It also shouldn't bounce while scrolling. Does anyone know where I could find a good one?

EDIT: To clarify, it needs to be at the top of the page, and not movable. Like the overlays you see here on Stack Overflow.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried jquery UI dialogs... http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: +1 Thanks, Krunal. But how do you position it at the top of the screen? And make it so that it cannot be moved? I need something like Stackoverflow's Badge notification overlay.

Comment: Or at least positioning it at the top of the screen. position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0 doesn't work. I think there's some conflict with .dialog().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jBar](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/) is one. It's pretty current, and I think does what you want.

Comment: Well, I'm an Electric Six fan. Reminded me of one of their songs.